# How to fill missing values in dataframe sequentially?

Tags: python, dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a data frame in PySpark that looks like this:

```
row_id, group_id
1,      1
2,      null
3,      null
4,      null
5,      5
6,      null
7,      null
8,      8
9,      null
10,     null
11,     null
12,     null
```

And so on: where row_id is sequential number (incremental and unique) and group_id is unique id of the group that starts where value show up first time and until next value.
The task is to fill in all nulls to the data frame like this:

```
row_id, group_id
1,      1
2,      1
3,      1
4,      1
5,      5
6,      5
7,      5
8,      8
9,      8
10,     8
11,     8
12,     8
```

There is an unknown number of records in each group (sample show small number) but it would be in 100s and length of data frame is in millions.

Answer (score 0):

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
from pyspark.sql.window import Window

# Create a Spark session
spark = SparkSession.builder.appName("example").getOrCreate()

# Your original dataframe
data = [(1, 1), (2, None), (3, None), (4, None), (5, 5), (6, None), (7, None), (8, 8), (9, None), (10, None), (11, None), (12, None)]
columns = ["row_id", "group_id"]
df = spark.createDataFrame(data, columns)

# Define a window specification
windowSpec = Window.orderBy("row_id").rowsBetween(Window.unboundedPreceding, 0)

# Use the last window function to fill null values with the last non-null value
filled_df = df.withColumn("group_id", F.last("group_id", ignorenulls=True).over(windowSpec))

# Show the resulting dataframe
filled_df.show()
+------+--------+
|row_id|group_id|
+------+--------+
|     1|       1|
|     2|       1|
|     3|       1|
|     4|       1|
|     5|       5|
|     6|       5|
|     7|       5|
|     8|       8|
|     9|       8|
|    10|       8|
|    11|       8|
|    12|       8|
+------+--------+
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).